# Python - Result returns generator instead of list (comprehension)

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, list-comprehension

I have one list as

```
x = ['1100000', '0110000', '0011000', '0001100', '0000110', '0000011']
```

I want to do bit wise XOR operation on each of the element against the whole array
so I have defined  a xor function as following

```
def x_o_r(val) :
    return "".join([ str(int(x) ^ int(y)) for (x,y) in val])
```

here val would be `zip(list('1100000'), list('0110000')]` and so on..

So I have defined a comprehension as following

```
[(x_o_r(z) for z in zip(list(a), list(b))) for a in x for b in x ]
```

it keeps on returning me

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000003704048>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000003704090>,.....]
```

I do not understand, I have a `[]` around the result.

I had even tried to convet individual generators to list(also tried `list()` function)

```
[([x_o_r(z)] for z in zip(list(a), list(b))) for a in x for b in x ]
```

Can any one point my mistake ?

**EDIT**

okay I took MArtijn advice and solved it by following expression

```
["".join([str(int(s) ^ int(d)) for (s,d) in zip(list(a), list(b))]) for a in x for b in x]
```

Comment: I really think you should be using `int()` with a base 2 here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer list comprehension has a *nested* generator expression:

```
[
    (x_o_r(z) for z in zip(list(a), list(b)))
    for a in x for b in x
]
```

Note the `(expr for target_list in expr)` part there; those are the generator objects you see in you output.

Make that a list comprehension too perhaps:

```
[[x_o_r(z) for z in zip(list(a), list(b))] for a in x for b in x]
```

However, if you wanted to apply the function on every pairing of elements from `x`, you probably wanted:

```
[x_o_r(zip(list(a), list(b))) for a in x for b in x]
```

Demo:

```
>>> [x_o_r(zip(list(a), list(b))) for a in x for b in x]
['0000000', '1010000', '1111000', '1101100', '1100110', '1100011', '1010000', '0000000', '0101000', '0111100', '0110110', '0110011', '1111000', '0101000', '0000000', '0010100', '0011110', '0011011', '1101100', '0111100', '0010100', '0000000', '0001010', '0001111', '1100110', '0110110', '0011110', '0001010', '0000000', '0000101', '1100011', '0110011', '0011011', '0001111', '0000101', '0000000']
```

You could use the [`itertools.product()` utility funcnion](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to produce the pairings:

```
from itertools import product
[x_o_r(zip(list(a), list(b))) for a, b in product(x, repeat=2)]
```

Next, adjust the `x_o_r` function to take *two* inputs, and perhaps use a more optimum approach using integers:

```
def x_o_r(a, b):
    return format(int(a, 2) ^ int(b, 2), '08b')

[x_o_r(a, b) for a, b in product(x, repeat=2)]
```

The latter version blows the old way out of the water when it comes to speed:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('[x_o_r(zip(list(a), list(b))) for a in x for b in x]', 'from __main__ import x_o_r, x', number=10000)
3.6057410949724726
>>> timeit.timeit('[x_o_r_new(a, b) for a, b in product(x, repeat=2)]', 'from __main__ import x_o_r_new, x, product', number=10000)
0.6972788329585455
```

Comment: that gives another error ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @Anand: Then you perhaps have an error *elsewhere*; I am merely pointing out where your generators are coming from.

Comment: thanks for point out (expr for target_list in expr) block. I solved using other technique. But I also like this [x_o_r(zip(list(a), list(b))) for a in x for b in x]